# mysql function is not execute as human imagine, why?

Tags: mysql

> ```
>  BEGIN  
>     DECLARE reslt VARCHAR(255);  
>     SET reslt = '1';  
>     SET reslt = concat(reslt,',','2');  
>     RETURN reslt;
>  END;
> ```

The result is not 1,2 but is 1 only. why ?

Comment: What datatype does the function return?

Comment: Thx Martin Smith, :)))

Comment: The return is integer.....

Comment: Change the return type to `VARCHAR(255)`